# Método genérico

Tags: java, genericos

Le comento que estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación en JAVA, Algo que me parece apasionante. Hace unos dia tengo un inconveniente con un método genérico al que no puedo encontrarle la vuelta. La cuestión es la siguiente: en una clase estandar tengo un método genérico que debería poder devolverme un array con el campo de una tabla de una base de datos. El campo, la tabla y el orden (ascendente/descendente) son los parámetros del método. A continuación les presento el código del mismo:

```
public <T> T[] getCampo(String campo, String tabla, boolean ascendente) {
    ResultSetMetaData parametros;
    String orden = (ascendente) ? " ASC" : " DESC";
    sentenciaSQL = "SELECT " + campo + " FROM " + tabla + " ORDER BY " + campo + orden;
    try {
        st = enlace.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs = st.executeQuery(sentenciaSQL);
        parametros = rs.getMetaData();
        System.out.println(rs.getMetaData().getColumnClassName(1));
        rs.next();
        return (T[]) rs.getArray(1).getArray();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(ProductosSQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), Inicio.appNombre, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return null;
    } finally {
        bbdd.setConneccionOff();
    }
}
```

El resultado que se obtiene es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la consola de salida este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta esta correcta puesto que posee solo un registro, pero no es nulo. Tambien la he probado con otras tablas donde hay mas registros pero el resultado es el mismo. Las clases de conección ya están probadas con otras áreas de la aplicación y funcionan a la perfección. Parce ser un error desde la base de datos, pero no logro ver que es. Desde ya gracias por su atención. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que no entra en el catch? Y ¿por qué no haces `rs.getString(1)`?

Comment: Casi seguro que si, pero no utilizo la sentencia propuesta debido que no quiero limitar solo a cadenas, esta es la razón de que el método sea paramétrico. Gracias